# Restricting body movement withing a specific length while dragging a gameobject in unity

Tags: unity, c#, physics

[image][image]

```
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 screen_sp=new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,screen_space.z);
    Vector3 cur_pos=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screen_sp)+offset;
        if(pendulum_object.gameObject != null && pendulum_object.gameObject.rigidbody!=null)
        {
                transform.position=cur_pos;
                    Debug.Log ("Pendulum is being dragged left"+transform.position);
                    Debug.Log("Mouse position is:"+Input.mousePosition);
                    Debug.Log("Current position is:"+cur_pos);
        }
}
```

**The problem is:The dragging of game object must be restricted to the length of string.**
The pendulum is joint using hinge joint to the world.

Comment: Try to find normalized direction vector between the string start and the end after physical simulation, then try move object at the `dir_vector*string_length` and see what happens. I'm not sure if this is possible because I'm not familiar with Unity. This comment is all that I can suggest about your question.

Comment: I don't know what that means?I just need that the Gameobject must be restricted to the length of the string,which is the hingeJoint anchor to which it is connected.

Comment: Here's [a question asking how to do this in the general sense](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/restrict-movement-within-a-radius).

Answer (score 1):

You should proceed in the following way

1) Get the input mouse position convert it to world co-ordinates

```
Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
```

2) Now calculate the directional Vector3 form anchor of the hinge joint to the input mouse position.

```
Vector3 diff = direction - Anchor.transform.position;
```

3) The last step will be to restrict the Position of the pendulum along this directional vector as per the string length (float) . By normalising we get the direction , then we clamp the magnitude to max String Length.

```
pendulum_object.transform.position = diff.normalized * Mathf.Clamp (diff.magnitude, 0, StringLength);
```

Note: If the pendulum is a child of a game object and if the scale and position differs. Then you need to use pendulum_object.transform.localPosition and also take care of the scaling factor.

Comment: Thank you for the respose,but that code didn't work.The pendulum now behave abnormally.I forgot to tell that the pendulum is swinging in y and z direction only.x axis position didn't change.

Comment: I have tested the code , I have used it once for on screen game pad to control the thumb from moving outside the surrounding circle. I am sure there must be some physics or hierarchy issue messing around. If you can share a project with the pendulum setup. I might be able to fix it.

Comment: This is the improved code,the pendulum is now restricted to y axis but no luck in the z axis.
`transform.position = new Vector3 (cur_pos.x,Mathf.Clamp (cur_pos.y,transform.position.y, pendulum_body.hingeJoint.connectedAnchor.y),Mathf.Clamp (cur_pos.z,-pendulum_object.transform.position.y,pendulum_object.transform.position.y));`

Comment: Sorry mate I am not expert enough to debug this logic , until I see the setup.

Comment: See the updated question.

Comment: By setup i didn't mean the screen shot of the inspector for the pendulum . I meant how the objects are placed in the scene that is what i need to see so that i can get it solved . Else it will be all guess work from my side . You need to share a new project with a scene containing the whole pendulum setup. You can remove all your personal scripts and just keep the code which handles the drag for the pendulum.